# Issue installing Ruby 2.7.2 on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm

I initially tried rbenv and followed [this person's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185912/need-help-installing-ruby-2-7-2-on-mac) but I ended up switching to RVM and getting this error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/thendralprabu/.rvm/log/1622423552_ruby-2.7.2/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here's the order of steps I attempted so far.

```
rvm install 2.7.2
rvm get master
rvm reinstall 2.7.2
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQzXc.png) what my make file is telling me, and my errors have been pointing me in the direction of the *include statement in the makefile, telling me that the file doesn't exist and I'm not sure how to address that.

Comment: Here's what my make file is telling me, and my errors have been pointing me in the direction of the *include statement in the makefile, telling me that the file doesn't exist and I'm not sure how to address that.

fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CFBase.h' file not found
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFString.h:13:10: note: did not find header 'CFBase.h' in framework 'CoreFoundation' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')

Comment: It helps to include details like that with an edit to the question where there's more room and better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MacOS are you using?

1. You can try to reinstalls the header files by this command:

   open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Where 10.14 is you current MacOS version.

2. If you on Big Sur you can try [this](https://techviewleo.com/install-xcode-command-line-tools-macos/) solution.
3. Also you can try install ruby with this flag:

   export optflags=" -Wno-nullability-completeness " && rvm install 2.7.2

PS. I think "ruby-on-rails" tag is unnecessary.

Comment: I'm using BigSur 11.4 and I looked under CommandLineTools and I don't have a folder called Packages

Comment: Then you can try second and third solutions. Let me know if they help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use brew

and rbenv
Follow this guide

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur

TO ruby install?

make sure to rehash.